# Typescript argument inference errors seem backwards

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at building a higher-order component in React but am running into some strange behavior in typescript. I want a HOC that only takes "compatible" components as input.  So this works fine:

(I've boiled this example down so that react doesn't complicate things)

```js
type RequiredProps = {
  content: string;
};
type ComponentType<T> = (props: T) => string;
    
function withDiv<T extends RequiredProps>(Component: ComponentType<T>) {
  const result = (props: T) => `
    <div>
      ${Component(props)}
    </div>
  `;
  return result;
}

    
function TestComponent(props: { content: string }) {
  return `<p>${props.content}</p>`;
}
    
const TestComponentWithDiv = withDiv(TestComponent);
```

But when I test trying to use a component that isn't compatible (doesn't have the required fields)

```js
export function BadComponent(props: { other: string }) {
  return `<p>${props.other}</p>`;
}
export const BadComponentWithDiv = withDiv(BadComponent);
```

I get what seems to be a backwards error:

```
Argument of type '(props: { other: string; }) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<RequiredProps>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Property 'other' is missing in type 'RequiredProps' but required in type '{ other: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

It's complaining that the `RequiredProps` doesn't have `other`, but it seems like it should complain that the argument is missing `content`.

Any idea what this is all about?

Using `"typescript": "^5.0.4"`,

Comment: How should we answer this? That's just how it is. In most cases, you want it to be like this. Now, are you looking for a way to *fix* this error, or do you just want an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: @jcalz No, that is exactly the point. I _want_ TS to have an error if the component passed in does not meet the interface (does not have a props type that conforms to `RequiredProps`). But in this case its complaining that the HOF doesn't conform to the function passed in.  I'm up for hearing tips about how to do this differently.  The lack of `content` is not harmless because the HOF uses it directly.

Comment: I'm afraid I've completely forgotten about this question since it was posted more than a month ago.  What's the specific question here?  Is it "*why* does the error message happen"?  Presumably inference fails, `T` falls back to the `RequiredProps` constraint, and then the actual type error is due to a violation of contravariance. I would write up an answer explaining but I'm wary of only hearing feedback about it a month from now.